# compile less files with grunt don t work!errors with EXEC command

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, less-css, grunt

After creating my theme I'm trying to compile less files.
but I'm having errors when : grunt exec:exercise1.
I'm using a windows machine.[image]

Comment: Have you tried just running grunt:exec first?

Comment: yes. i installed node.js, run the npm install commands and then run the exec command. even if i run the exec command with the luma theme i have the same errors

Comment: I reinstall magento without creating a new theme. and even when i run the exec on the luma theme i got the same errors.and it deletes all the files on pub/static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve the issue for windows users (windows 7) when trying to run grunt.
if you got symlinks errors when trying to do : grunt exec
ln -fs out/Release/node node
more details here : http://www.ahtik.com/blog/fixing-your-virtualbox-shared-folder-symlink-error/

Answer (score 2):

I have tried so many things to solve this on windows xampp but finally it's working with simple thing: **Run CMD command prompt with administrator privilege** to run your commands.

Answer (score 0):

The luma theme depends on the blank theme to have all of it's assets compiled and linked to in the pub directory, otherwise it will have missing less variables, mixins, etc, that it expects to find from the blank theme. The same is true for any theme that uses the luma theme as a dependency. If you you try to run `grunt exec:luma` before `grunt exec:blank` you will get errors. To fix this, the first time you are compiling your less files in a theme that depends on another theme, you should run `grunt exec` without any themes in the command and grunt will compile each theme in order. To make sure grunt knows you are using blank or luma as a dependency, you should make sure your theme.xml file included in your theme has the parent node where the value is the theme your theme inherits from.

Read through this guide thoroughly and you shouldn't encounter any problems. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Comment: I tried to run only grunt exec after cleaning and got the same errors;

[Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
>> Cannot create a symlink for "/vagrant/data/magento2/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/source/_reset.less" and place it to "/vagrant/data/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/_reset.less" Warning!file_get_contents(/vagrant/data/magento2/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---e92_INTERCEPTION): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Grunt will not help you much. I got symlink error when use grunt.
I only use this commands **setup:static-content:deploy** . Make sure you get all required less file to your theme before run above command

Example theme luma.
Files missing that i added to my custom theme

```
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_actions-toolbar.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_breadcrumbs.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_buttons.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_dropdowns.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_email-base.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_email-extend.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_email-variables.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_forms.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_icons.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_loaders.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_messages.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_pages.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_popups.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_price.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_rating.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_sections.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_tooltips.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/_typography.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/components/_modals.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_actions-toolbar.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_breadcrumbs.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_buttons.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_dropdowns.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_forms.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_grids.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_icons.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_layout.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_loaders.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_messages.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_navigation.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_pages.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_popups.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_rating.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_sections.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_tables.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_tooltips.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_typography.less
    new file:   app/design/frontend/Magento/market/web/css/source/lib/_utilities.less
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on my local with Windows 10, wamp, and running commands via Babun. I closed out my terminal and started a session as an administrator, and now Im able to process the commands without errors.